# Several Ladder Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

If I have a term $\sum_{i} \hat{a}_{i} \hat{a}_{-i}$ that I want act on it with the  $|n\rangle$ eigenstate, how would I handle the $-i$ index?  I know $\hat{a}\, | n\rangle = \sqrt{n}\,| n-1\rangle$, but how do I deal with the indices?  If both indices were negative, I could reindex them to positive $i$'s and use the ladder operator above because both operators will be acting on the same particle.  Could I reindex only one component of this term so that both indices will now be positive?  I doubt this, so then I looked at occupation number representation.  This didn't seem correct because we are dealing with the same index in both components of the term, only one component is negative.  It didn't make sense to me to have a negative occupation number.  Thus I am unsure how to handle this negative index in the term.

Comment: What is the context in which the indices are being used? Normally, I would interpret the indices to denote the Hilbert space the operator is acting on: $\hat a_i$ acts on the Hilbert space $H_i$ where the complete Hilbert space is the tensor product $H=\otimes_iH_i$.

Comment: It is in terms of an oscillator problem.

Comment: The i's are multiple oscillators.

Comment: I expect either $\hat a_{-i}$ is a wierd notation for $\hat a^\dagger_i$, or if $\hat a_{-i}$ refers to an oscillator labelled $-i$ then this is a coupling term.

Comment: The notation $\hat a_{-i}\equiv\hat a_i^\dagger$ would be wierd as because sometimes ladder operators are indicated with $\pm$ subscripts to indicated raising or lowering but by convention $\hat a$ is the lowering operator ($a$ for anhillation).

Comment: It is from a coupling term.  I am trying to figure out how to definitively deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would interpret the indices to denote the Hilbert space the operator is acting on: $\hat a_i$ acts on the Hilbert space $H_i$ where the complete Hilbert space is the tensor product $H=\otimes_iH_i$. If the system is a set of $2N+1$ oscillators labelled by integer $i\in\left[-N,N\right]$ then we can use the orthonornal basis $\left\{|n_{-N}\rangle|n_{-N+1}\rangle\ldots|n_{N-1}\rangle|n_N\rangle\middle|\forall n_i\in\mathbb Z^+\forall i\right\}$.

The operator $\sum_{i=0}^N\hat a_i\hat a_{-i}$ has the action on $|n_{-N}\rangle|n_{-N+1}\rangle\ldots|n_{N-1}\rangle|n_N\rangle$ as follows:

$$\sum_{i=0}^N\hat a_i\hat a_{-i}|n_{-N}\rangle|n_{-N+1}\rangle\ldots|n_{N-1}\rangle|n_N\rangle=\left(\sqrt{n_Nn_{-N}}|n_{-N}-1\rangle|n_{-N+1}\rangle\ldots|n_{N-1}\rangle|n_N-1\rangle\right)+\left(\sqrt{n_{N-1}n_{-N+1}}|n_{-N}\rangle|n_{-N+1}-1\rangle\ldots|n_{N-1}-1\rangle|n_N\rangle\right)+\ldots+\left(\sqrt{n_{1}n_{-1}}|n_{-N}\rangle\ldots|n_{-1}-1\rangle|n_{0}\rangle|n_{1}-1\rangle\ldots|n_N\rangle\right)+\left(\sqrt{n_{0}\left(n_{0}-1\right)}|n_{-N}\rangle\ldots|n_{0}-2\rangle\ldots|n_N\rangle\right)$$

If we change our notation so that the order of kets does not define which Hilbert space they belong to but instead a subscript label does ( $|\psi\rangle_i$ belongs to $H_i$) then we can use the more concise expression:

$$\sum_{i=0}^N\hat a_i\hat a_{-i}\bigotimes_j|n_j\rangle_j\\=\sqrt{n_0\left(n_0-1\right)}|n_0-2\rangle_0\bigotimes_{j\ne0}|n_j\rangle_j+\sum_{i=1}^N\sqrt{n_in_{-i}}|n_i-1\rangle_i|n_{-i}-1\rangle_{-i}\bigotimes_{j\ne i,-i}|n_j\rangle_j$$

Note this operator is not Hermitian. Also, the sum is quite messy and so I would in most cases leave it as the left-hand side but hopefully, it gives you intuition for what the operator is doing: creating a superposition of states with each state having a different $i,-i$ pair lowered.

Do let me know if I have miss interpreted the context.

Comment: This is similar to the idea I originally had.  It looked messy and I was hoping that there might be a justification for a simplified form.  Would you agree that if reindexing is possible, i.e. $\sum_{i} a_{-i}a_{-i} \rightarrow \sum_{i} a_{i}a_{i}$, it has to be over the whole term and not just a single component of it?  I don't feel $i$ would be a dummy index because there is a $-i$ and an $i$, not two $i's$ of the same sign.  Do you agree?

Comment: I have added a more concise form to my answer, but it uses less conventional notation to achieve this. The re-indexing you have stated would be fine, but in your original question the operator was $\sum_{i} \hat{a}_{i} \hat{a}_{-i}
$ not $\sum_{i} a_{-i}a_{-i}$ and so there is no re-indexing that will convert between these two operators as $i\to-i$ would just reverse the order of the $\hat a$ operators not make both $i$ or $-i$.